# Global Proxy for a Network Adapter on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, proxy, connection-sharing

I'm trying to share my Internet Connection with another system over Windows ICS. My system connects to the Internet via WiFi and shares it over to another system over LAN. This works perfectly without any issues. (Yes, I know, it's not a usual situation)

But, I need to add proxy settings in the middle to that I can see all the traffic as well as block some of it before it gets to the ICS client.

Say, I connect to the Internet using `Wireless Adapter 1`, and then I use Windows Internet Connection Sharing to serve internet over `Local Area Connection 1`. I need to add a proxy **only** to traffic that goes through the `Local Area Connection 1`, that is only the data used by the ICS client.

Any help is appreciated, TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Proxy is not same as router. It understands the request and re-generate the request on behalf of the original requester(Client). So there is no Proxy for all network traffics. We only have the proxy for some specific usages, such as Web proxy, Email Proxy, FTP proxy.

Also, as far as I know, the Windows doesn't provides the built-in proxy server.
So you may need to install some additional proxy server software on it.

If all you want is to monitoring the traffic from the LAN adaptor, you may just install the wireshark and perform a network capture on the LAN adaptor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I host a proxy server for network administration over my local network. It's a proxy server for web and ftp, I just want all the traffic to go through this proxy before it reaches the client.

Comment: Then you just need to configure the proxy settings on all of your clients. And let the proxy server use the ICS client as gateway so that traffic from all clients can be forwarded to your ICS client.

Comment: The client does not have options to add a proxy server, which is the main reason why I was using Windows ICS in the first place. (My network also requires browser based authentication to connect to the internet)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, the proxy settings must be configured on the client, so that the IP address of the proxy server can be used as the destination IP address of the request. If we didn't configure the proxy settings on the client, the request will be sent to the destination directly.